# Import Excel table into Access table?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to import a specified table in excel into Access. Once a user turns their data in an excel spreadsheet into a table, I know that the data should be clean, with no subheader and no merged cells. However, in using the Sub

'''

```
 Public Sub ImportExcelSpreadsheet(FileName As String, tableName As String, Range As String)
 
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tableName, FileName, True, Range

 End Sub
 

 'When I try to run the sub the values are as follows
 ExcelImport.ImportExcelSpreadsheet Me.txtFileName, FSO.GetFileName(Me.txtFileName), "tbl_IOList[#All]" 'Where tbl_IOList[#All] is the range
```

I have been successful when entering the Range as "$A$1:$L$116", but it does not work with "tbl_IOList[#All]"

Comment: did you try replacing `"tbl_IOList[#All]"` with `Range("tbl_IOList[#All]").Address`?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly insert data from Access, to Excel. Try the code below an feedback.

```
Sub InsertInto()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, row As Long
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
            "Data Source=C:\your_path\Test.accdb;"

    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "tblYourTable", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

    row = 3    ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row))

        With rs
            .AddNew    ' create a new record
            .Fields("ID") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value
            .Fields("Product") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row).Value
            .Fields("ProdDate") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & row).Value
            .Update
        End With
        row = row + 1
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

This runs in Excel, and pushes data to MS Access. If you want to run the process from Access, and import from Excel, you can try to do it this way.

```
Sub ImportDataFromExcel()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
        "C:\your_path\Test.mdb"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open strConn
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
        lastcolumn = .Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))
    End With
        
        'therow = 1
        
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            'r = rng.Row
            'If r > 1 Then
                strSQL = "UPDATE PersonInformation SET " & _
                    "FName='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "LName='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "Address='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "Age=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value & " WHERE " & _
                    "ID=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
                conn.Execute strSQL
            'End If
            'r = r + 1
        Next i
        
    
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That’s for the answer. But I meant if I define my table as a “Table” by selecting the range and pressing ctrl + T. The naming the table in excel. Say I name it tblExcel. I what to use the tblExcel which is stored as a Range in the Formulas

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Maybe you can ask a new question. Usually posting a before picture and after picture helps.